# Jenkins master: Not able to login with admin:admin

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins master in a Docker container. Everything is working fine but suddenly the container stopped I started again but now I am Not able to login.

I am getting "Invalid username or password"

Tried 1:
changed to false

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Tried 2: 
I changed the password hash of config file inside user/admin

What should I do? How will I login??
P.S I am restarting the container as there is no jenkins service available.

docker ps output:

```
ae023234df49        Saas_jenkinsmaster   "/bin/tini -- /usr..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   jenkinsmaster
```

Comment: have you restarted the jenkins after updating the config file to false/

Comment: @error404: I tried both the command

systemctl restart jenkins.service
service jenkins restart

but getting jenkins: unrecognized service

So I am restarting the container.

Comment: you have volume mounted, right ? Can you check if the respective jenkins volume has been updated on the host config file ? How is the volume mount of jenkins working in your case ?

Comment: Yes I do. I am using /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home. 

I tried changing host config.xml as well.

Comment: what is the output of `docker ps`

Comment: @error404: I added the output in the question.

Comment: join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194934/jenkins-issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194937/discussion-between-error404-and-vikas-rathore).

Comment: I have pinged you there @error404